# setTint() on half image

Tags: javascript, phaser

I'm developing a game where I need to paint half of a image when the user is either wrong or right. To paint the image, I'm using `setTint()` to paint the image the color I need, but it paints the whole image, is there any way I can paint only half, using setTint or another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with `phaser`, but a general way to achieve this is to create two Image objects, each one having half of the picture, and position the second below the first, so it looks like one complete image.

At the moment the user answers, you can use `setTint()` to change only half of the picture.

This method has its limitations, as you can't dynamically split an image to more parts this way, but it is a simple method that gets the desired result.

Comment: Yean, I was trying to avoid this, because i have a lot of images to apply this, but I think i'll have to use this method.
But I'll keep looking for something else, if I find I'll post here!
Thanks so much man, have a really nice day!

Comment: @ArthurOliveira You can also do the same thing by using shaders, which can be more automated, but I'm not familiar enough with `phaser` to know how it handles them.

Comment: I don't know much about shaders, but for sure I'll look for and try to use it. Thanks so much man!!